# Unable to rename folders in C++ Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I create a new c++ Project in Visual Studio Community edition, I can add folders, but I can't name them (as shown in the below picture).

My project file is located at: **C:\temp**
I am running Windows 10.

I have tried restarting VS as well as running as Administrator, but it has not resolved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

1. Click on Save as
2. Save it to your Desktop
3. Rename it manually outside VS

It should work.